# Azure Databricks sentiment analysis doesn't work

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-databricks

I'm using Azure Databricks and I want to do a text sentiment analysis with the following code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
import synapse.ml
from synapse.ml.cognitive import *

# Create a dataframe that's tied to it's column names
df_sentences = spark.createDataFrame([
  ("I am so happy today, its sunny!", "en-US"),
  ("this is a dog", "en-US"),s
  ("I am frustrated by this rush hour traffic!", "en-US")
], ["text", "language"])

# Run the Text Analytics service with options
sentiment = (TextSentiment()
    .setTextCol("text")
    .setLocation("eastasia") # Set the location of your cognitive service
    .setSubscriptionKey(cognitive_service_key)
    .setOutputCol("sentiment")
    .setErrorCol("error")
    .setLanguageCol("language"))

# Show the results of your text query in a table format

display(sentiment.transform(df_sentences).select("text", col("sentiment")[0].getItem("sentiment").alias("sentiment")))
```

This doesn't work.. Here is the full error with the details:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.param.ServiceParamJsonProtocol$

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.cognitive.TextSentiment.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.param.ServiceParamJsonProtocol$
   at com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.param.ServiceParam.<init>(JsonEncodableParam.scala:62)
   at com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.cognitive.HasSubscriptionKey.$init$(CognitiveServiceBase.scala:130)
   at com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.cognitive.CognitiveServicesBaseNoHandler.<init>(CognitiveServiceBase.scala:306)
   at com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.cognitive.TextAnalyticsBase.<init>(TextAnalytics.scala:53)
   at com.microsoft.azure.synapse.ml.cognitive.TextSentiment.<init>(TextAnalytics.scala:288)
   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
   at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
   at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:380)
   at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:250)
   at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
   at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
   at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:251)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I'm running 10.4 (includes Apache Spark 3.2.1, Scala 2.12) cluster and have synapseml_2.12:0.10.0 installed. Does someone know what goes wrong?

Comment: Post the bigger stacktrace

Comment: Not sure if you mean this? Check out edit

Answer (score 0):

Generally this error is caused by incompatible versions of libraries with spark and Scala.

To get rid of this error you need to Uninstall `synapseml_2.12:0.10.0` and install `synapseml_2.12:0.10.1`

Maven coordinates - `com.microsoft.azure:synapseml_2.12:0.10.1`

[image]